# How to solve a complex group by sql query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like:

```
vending_machine_id | timestamp  | manual |
              543  | 2011-06-08 | true |
              543  | 2011-05-05 | false|
              543  | 2010-12-12 | true |
              542  | 2013-01-29 | true |
              542  | 2012-01-29 | true |
```

All I want is to select most recent date of each vending_machine_id with a third field (`manual`) to have `true/false` (if there are both `true` and `false` realdings for that vending_machine_id, `true` (if there are only true manual readings), or `false`.

I have done this so much:

```
SELECT vmrp.vending_machine_id, max(timestamp), readingMethodSelect.readingMethod
FROM vending_machine_reading_product as vmrp,
(select 
    distinct(manual) as readingMethod, vending_machine_id
    FROM vending_machine_reading_product
    WHERE vending_machine_id in (542, 543, 821, 824)
    group by vending_machine_id, readingMethod) as readingMethodSelect
WHERE vmrp.vending_machine_id = readingMethodSelect.vending_machine_id
GROUP BY vmrp.vending_machine_id, readingMethodSelect.readingMethod
ORDER BY vmrp.vending_machine_id, max(timestamp) desc
```

And it prints:

```
542;"2013-01-29 10:59:47";f
543;"2011-06-08 05:43:26";f
543;"2011-06-08 05:43:26";t
821;"2013-02-12 00:56:56";f
824;"2013-02-11 05:52:55";f
```

As you noticed, what I still don't know how to do is to have a single row with `543` vending_machine_id and that line to have at the end `f/t`. (because this `id` has both true and false manual reading types).

Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Comment: so you want 'true' even if timestamp > for a false, right? I would "ORDER BY [manual] DESC, timestamp" (so 'true' are on top if there's any) and SELECT TOP 1 (OR SELECT .... LIMIT 1, whatever the syntax is :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  vending_machine_id, 
        MAX(timestamp) "TimeStamp",
        CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT manual) > 1
            THEN 'True/False'
            ELSE MAX(manual)
        END AS "Manual"
-- WHERE ..add condition here..
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY vending_machine_id
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d31ac/4)

Comment: This is the answer according to what he requested, BUT I'm thinking he meant just true or false.  But, you get the points for getting the right answer and providing the SQLFiddle.

Comment: @NickDeVore It is based on the OP, *"..to have `true/false` (if there are both true and false readings for that vending_machine_id, `true` (if there are only true manual readings), or `false`."* Or maybe I didn't understand the question. hehe

Comment: Thanks, this should work  indeed, but manual column is of boolean type and I receive some strange error: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d8b60/2

Comment: @CristianBoariu I'm unsure you'll need the CAST. It doesn't work in sqlfiddle as it doesn't understand the postgre-specific aggregate func. (bool_or) but probably will be OK in your db.env.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want:

```
select vmrp.vending_machine_id, MAX(timestamp),
       bool_and(manual)
from vmrp.vending_machine_id
group by vmrp.vending_machine_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT  vending_machine_id, 
        MAX(timestamp) "TimeStamp",
        array_agg(distinct manual order by manual desc)
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY vending_machine_id
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d8b60/3).